# Python library to perform stratified KFold cross-validation in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, cross-validation

I have a set of data on which I would like to train a Neural Net, although I believe my question pertains to any type of machine learning.

My data falls into two classes, however I have many more examples of class one than I do of class two. Before I go ahead and train a neural net on my data, I intend to split the data into 3 independent groups (Training, Validation and Testing), and within each one, duplicate the data I have for class one enough times so that I have equal amounts of data from each class in that group.

This is really tedious to do, and I'm willing to bet that other people have had the same problem. Is there a python library that does this for me? Or at least part of it?

**tl;dr:** I want a python library that splits my data into 3 parts and equalizes the amount of data I have in each class without throwing away data

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: If you need to do this several times in your program(s), then write a general function to take care of it. It's fundamentally a simple thing to do -- no need to rely on an external library to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use scikit-learn. Copy pasting KeironO's answer from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1711:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold

def load_data():
    # load your data using this function

def create model():
    # create your model using this function

def train_and_evaluate__model(model, data[train], labels[train], data[test], labels[test)):
    model.fit...
    # fit and evaluate here.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_folds = 10
    data, labels, header_info = load_data()
    skf = StratifiedKFold(labels, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=True)

    for i, (train, test) in enumerate(skf):
            print "Running Fold", i+1, "/", n_folds
            model = None # Clearing the NN.
            model = create_model()
            train_and_evaluate_model(model, data[train], labels[train], data[test], labels[test))
```